# Is this the proper way to get a string back from an sql query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying a DB and want that query in string format, not object so what I've been doing is:

```
$StringHolder = "";
$sql = (some sql)
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $StringHolder = $row;
    }

$StringHolder = implode($StringHolder);
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this? As you can probably tell I'm very new to this PHP.

So, one of my actual chunks of code is:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$databaseBuilding);
$tenantIdSql= "SELECT tenant_id FROM rooms WHERE room_num = '".$roomNum."'";
$tenantIdObj= mysqli_query($connection, $tenantIdSql);
$tenantID = "";
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($tenantIdObj){
        $tenantID = $row;
    }
$tenantID = implode($tenantID);
```

Comment: `$value = $row['yourColumnName'];`

Comment: `$StringHolder .= $row['yourColumnName'];`

Comment: 'string format, not object' means ? can you explain more or by any example ?

Comment: and what it the output of the current code you have? and the expected output you want?

Comment: it's outputting what I want. It gives me the tenantID as a string, "T554-899". However I just threw this together based on what I'd been reading to actually do this. It seems like a lot of processing just to get a string and I wondered if I was making it more complicated than it need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$tenantID_array = array();
if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($tenantIdObj){
    $tenantID_array[] = $row['tenant_id'];
}

$tenantID_str = implode(",",$tenantID_array);
echo $tenantID_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to replace `$tenantID = $row;` with `$tenantID = $row['tenant_id'];` and if that is not working well then try `$tenantID = $row[0];`